# Chrome/Chromium login problem

Tags: login, google-chrome

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 and I love it

But there's a little problem with browsers,I both tried chrome and chromium browsers but I cant login my google account for sync bookmarks etc.

I already searched problem on google but couldnt find a solution .
Ps: I already tried clear cookies ( with clean browser lol)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1.)**  Click on the Menu

[image]

---

**Step 2.)**  Select "Settings" on the menu.

[image]

---

**Step 3.)**  Select "Advanced Sync Everthing" under "Sing In" group shown as Orange

[image]

---

**Step 4.)** Select "Ok" on the dialog, and make sure the Combobox is on the value as "Sync everything" shown as green.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the very same problem, and the only way I found to solve it was disconnecting my browser from my Google account, and logging in again.

Comment: Um, his problem is he can't even connect his Google account in the first place.

Comment: How do you know that?What if (as in my case) he/she had his/her browser synchronized, and, suddenly, the browser lost its ability to get synchronized? And then (I quote) "I cant login my google account for sync bookmarks etc.".

Comment: I've had the same problem. Disconnecting and turning off all syncing, then connecting and selecting my syncing options worked.